# How to build an Android Library that contains resources (layouts, drawables, etc.)?

Tags: android, xamarin

I am building an app (using xamarin) with a "pro vs home" scenario: Theres a professional version and a home version, targeting different customers/scenarios.

Yet those apps share some functionality and UI.

**Is it possible to build a class library for android, that contains resource files like layouts, drawables, strings, etc., which can then be used in multiple android app projects?**

My current solution is to just have abstract `Fragment` classes in a library, and override `OnCreateView` in the different clients. But this turned out to be a little messy and sometimes hard to understand/debug later.

Comment: In a "pure" Android java app you normally go creating a project library in this ways:  https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html and https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Building-your-own-Android-library.
In Xamarin you can go in the same way (but the library must be written in C# and added as a dependency in both variants)

Comment: Look more info about '.aar vs .jar'

Answer (score 1):

You can have Drawables, Strings, Attributes and other Resources in your library, this has been supported for a long time.

If you have Activities in your Library, you may need to manually register them in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: it is not working. i moved all my drawable folders into android class library. build is working fine but once i run the project, it crashes and cant find resources. I am guessing that it has something with resource.designer.cs having different namespace than actual android project. do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It is completely possible to have library projects that contain all your app resources.
You can do the same for iOS as well.

Adding the Activity/Fragment code in there as well might cause some issues though and will make it allot harder to understand and debug, personally I don't like that.
My suggestion is to rather create the activities/fragments for each app and maybe have a Portable Class Library with shared code that you can use for the other apps.